# Java ArrayList issue

Tags: java, arraylist

I need some help with a line of code in a program that I am writing.  I feel like it's going to be some stupid mistake but I just can't seem to figure out what it is...

```
ArrayList<Integer> knockSequence;               //Default knockSequence
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> customSequences;  //used to store custom sequences for client after   first connection
ArrayList<ServerClient> connectedClients;       //List of connected clients
//...
public void giveNewSequence(ArrayList<Integer> newSequence, ServerClient client) //client MUST be in connectedClients in order for this to work
{
    customSequences.get(connectedClients.indexOf(client)) = newSequence;
}
```

Why won't the line "customSequences.get(......." work? The error I'm getting is saying that it is looking for a variable but a value is being found.  Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: In the future, please post the *exact* error message.

Comment: Sorry, first post here.  Will remember to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why won't the line "customSequences.get(......." work?

You're trying to assign a value to the result of a method call. *That's* what doesn't work. You can only use the assignment operator with a variable.

I suspect you want:

```
customSequences.set(connectedClients.indexOf(client), newSequence);
```

You should also consider using a single collection with a composite type which contains the knock, custom sequence and connected client, rather than managing three separate collections where the values are related by index (which is what I suspect you've got here). You might want to use a map as well, rather than a list.

Comment: Thank you for the advice EDIT: the code you posted works, thanks a lot!